# Not able to access Create method from instance of DatabaseProviderFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Enterprise Lib config for database access.

When I am trying to access Create method from instance of DatabaseProviderFactory then I am getting below error
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'name

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a non-static member like that, if you want to initialize Db with default then please use a constructor for it

for example, initializing in a default constructor

```
public class clsInvoiceDB
{
    DatabaseProviderFactory factory;
    Database objDatabase;

    //this is the constructor
    public clsInvoiceDB()
    {
        factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
        objDatabase = factory.Create("connString");
    }

}
```

This will assign assign objDatabase when you create a new instance of it.